# Cannot use RelativeLayout from XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms (PCL) cross-platform application project on Visual Studio 2017, and am facing a number of issues related to the use of  `RelativeLayout` components from the XAML files of my views:

- In XAML, the only member of the `RelativeLayout` namespace available through Intellisense suggestions is `RelativeLayout.BoundsConstraint`, it does not suggest any of the other constraints such as `RelativeLayout.XConstraint`, `RelativeLayout.YConstraint`, `RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint`...
- If I include any of those non-suggested constraints on a control nonetheless, my application crashes when loading the view at runtime on Android (cannot test on iOS for now).
- However, configuring a `RelativeLayout` programmatically works as expected and it renders properly.
- Finally, the same problem also happens on any newly created Xamarin.Forms projet, and updating the Xamarin.Forms package through NuGet has not been of any help.

I obviously have some sort of environment configuration inconsistency, but I have not been able to pinpoint the origin of the problem.

*Xamarin.Forms package version: v2.3.4.247*

Comment: has you can see in this post, Jason Smith says "don't use RelativeLayout (if possible)"... You could try with "Grid" http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips

Comment: This post contains quite a lot of useful performance tips indeed, not only related to this issue. Thanks for sharing. I will try to achieve the result I am aiming at using another layout, but leaving this post open for when using a `RelativeLayout` will not be avoidable.

Comment: Please, I'm having the exact same issue would anyone be able to help me, thanks.

Comment: @daveguru In the end I did not manage to solve this issue. I ended up using grid layouts instead, as recommended by Alessandro.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

That is IntelliSense issue, not Xamarin.Form's issue you still can use these in XAML like this 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/

Comment: Indeed, but this does not solve my missing attributes issues, and using `RelativeLayout` from XAML without Intellisense is very error-prone.